# What factorial number to get a good approximation of the matrix exponential?

Tags: matrices, factorial, matrix-exponential, truncation-error

$$e^X = \sum_{k=0}^N{1 \over k!}X^k$$

Assume that $X \in \Re^{nxn}$ is random matrix. What number $N$ should I use to get a good accuracy compared if $N = \infty$?

Is this possible to measure?

Comment: Why does $N$ have to be a factorial number?

Comment: Choose a suitable norm and control $$\text{Error}_N=\lVert e^X-\sum_{k=0}^N\frac1{k!}X^k\rVert $$by choosing $N$.

Comment: The prospect is grim. See [*Nineteen dubious ways to compute the exponential of a matrix*](https://doi.org/10.1137/S00361445024180).

Comment: @user1551 can you show some examples?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't any.

Comment: Have you tried the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Please, show me the simplest way to solve matrix exponential.

Comment: Try the case where the matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: @user1551 The actual PDF of the article is paywalled, but can be found [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf).

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Great! matlab example expm2 is the solution! Works great!